# NoSuchMethodError : The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null. Receiver : null tried calling 'isNotEmpty'

Tags: flutter, dart

This is an ebook app in which I fetch data from API and in this, the books display completely fine but when I click on books to read this red screen error appear, and am still confused whether its an app error or on the PHP side but on debug panel in vs code when clicking on error this lines highlighted.

In bookview.dart

```
if (bookitem[0].bookDescription.isNotEmpty)
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
```

and this is the second line highlighted click on the error
in bookview.dart

```
ScreenUtilInit(
        builder: () => Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(bookitem[0].authorName),
            backgroundColor: _gradientColor1,
          ),
```

and this is the error on the console:

Exception caught by widgets library

```
 The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building LayoutBuilder:
 The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null.
 Receiver: null
 Tried calling: isNotEmpty

 The relevant error-causing widget was
 ScreenUtilInit
 package:ebook/screen/viewbook.dart:652
 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
 #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:68:5)
 #1      _ViewBookScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
 package:ebook/screen/viewbook.dart:846
```

[image]

Comment: The error is because of `bookitem[0].bookDescription` which is null. Try debugging using breakpoints or print logs.

Answer (score 0):

The **bookitem** are array and that intially are null than you need following code to help you and check you first condition.

```
if (bookitem != null && bookitem[0].bookDescription.isNotEmpty)
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
```

Comment: its not working still the same error

Comment: Ok , you can add condition **title**  in appbar. Like this title: Text(bookitem !=null && bookitem.length > 0 && bookitem[0].authorName),